# mapear eventos de teclado jquery - Acessibilidade

Tags: jquery, acessibilidade

Gostaria de fazer um menu acessível, podendo ser retraído com esc e navegável por tab, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer? por keyup, keydown, alguém teria um bom exemplo para mencionar?

Comment: A algum tempo eu criei [essa "biblioteca"](https://github.com/Lautert/KeyMap) para fins parecidos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma de você fazer isso é mapeando as teclas que vai usar, pois cada tecla tem sua numeração.

No seu caso capture a tecla pressionada, defina qual elemento DOM você deseja trabalhar, ou seja, irá receber o evento do teclado e aplique o código que quiser após a validação da tecla.

Você pode usar o evento Keypress da biblioteca jQuery, veja o exemplo de como detectar o comando na página inteira, em qualquer lugar onde esteja o cursor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).keypress(function(e){
    //Enter
    if(e.wich == 13 || e.keyCode == 13){
        //Botão responsável por exibir a lista do menu;
    }
    // Esc
    if(e.wich == 27 || e.keyCode == 27){
        //Botão responsável por esconder a lista do menu;
    }
  })
});
```

Você pode fazer isso usando *JavaScript* ou JQuery:

- [*JavaScript*](https://odesenvolvedor.andafter.org/publicacoes/tabela-de-key-codes-para-javascript_1464.html)
- [*JQuery*](http://clubedosgeeks.com.br/programacao/javascript/eventos-do-teclado-com-javascript-e-jquery-2)

Comment: muito bem explicado, obrigada.